# Math.random() Code Source?

Tags: actionscript-3, random

from the ActionScript 3.0 documentation:

> **Global Functions > Math.random()**
>
> *Returns a pseudo-random number n,
>   where 0 <= n < 1. The number returned
>   is calculated in an undisclosed
>   manner, and is "pseudo-random" because
>   the calculation inevitably contains
>   some element of non-randomness.*

i'm interested in reading the source code for Math.random() and assume it's the same in other C-based languages like AS3.  is it available for viewing?

can anyone explain which elements make the code pseudo-random and why?  is it impossible to create a function that returns a truely random value?

Comment: The implementation can be different (and likely is) between different ActionScript implementations: the Windows Flash player might use one implementation, the Mac Flash player might use another, and Scaleform GFx might use yet another implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of [Pseudo Random Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators) functions - the most common one if you aren't doing high end crypto is probably a linear congruent - see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) for a description and links to implementation code.

Answer (score 1):

To get real random numbers you can use some web services such as [random.org](http://random.org)
It uses randomness from atmospheric noise

Answer (score 0):

A lot rely on the system time if I remember rightly since it changes so quick.
If you hit the same sydtem time, get the same random out.
As for true random, not possible, theres no bit in a computer that wasnt set. You could say it would be random if you went into something elses memory space and grabbed something, but thats all deterministic just like the time.

Comment: Not quite, a PRN will always generate the same sequence of numbers if you start with the same 'seed'. A common way to get a new random seed is to use the system time. But if you reseed the generator too quickly the time value, which only changes once per second, stays the same.  It's a common mistake to reseed rand()

Comment: Not quite? Maybe I'm missing something, but you've said the same as me in a little more detail.